# Создайте дизайн молнии

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь воссоздать символ молнии от "The Flash (DC Comics)" (или знак на футболке, которую носит Sheldon Cooper из "The Big Bang Theory" ) в CSS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот символ будет действовать, как система звездного рейтинга, но вместо  этого будет - "система рейтинга молний".

Однако, поскольку я пытаюсь свести HTML к минимуму, то я бы хотел, чтобы в основном это был   стиль CSS.

*Ниже пример моего кода:*

```css
 position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.circ:hover{
  background:gray;
  }
.circ:hover .bolt{
  background:gold;
  }
.circ {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px black;
}
.bolt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 30%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: perspective(200px) skewX(-10deg) rotateX(15deg);
}
.bolt:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform:  ;
}
/*
.bolt:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-40%;left:20%;
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  background:inherit;
  transform:perspective(50px) skewX(-10deg) rotateX(45deg);
  }*/
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="circ">

    <div class="bolt"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но не знаю, как дальше продолжать отсюда.
Я попытался использовать свойство `perspective`, хотя я не знаю, что у меня уже есть ли до сих пор обработка  по этому свойству - в основном потому, что я немного запутался относительно того, что `perspective` делает со свойствами `:before` и `:after`, когда они применяются к родительскому элементу.

Выбрал для этого CSS, так как белый фон и цвет молнии будут меняться при щелчке, и ещё потому, что я знаю, как это сделать с помощью CSS.

Знаю, что SVG может быть лучшим вариантом здесь, но я не смог изучить SVG из-за ограничений по времени, поэтому  предпочел бы использовать «то, что я знаю, как использовать», то есть CSS.

Перевод вопроса: [Create a lightning bolt design (like The Flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30640309/7394871)@jbutler483

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640309/create-a-lightning-bolt-design-like-the-flash/30641358#30641358

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Однозначно `svg` тут 100%-ое решение, но предложу еще свой кривой css вариант) :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.wrap {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
/*   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.z {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lg {
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewX(-50deg) rotate(-40deg) translate(-78%, -82%);
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.lightning-border{
  background: #d4c6cb;  
  width: 42px;
  height: 130px; 
  left: 50.5%;
}

.lightning{
  background: #fbe028;
  width: 35px;
  height: 120px;
}

.lg:before,
.lg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.lightning:before {
  top: -130px;
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom: 150px solid #fbe028;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.lightning:after {
  top: 90px;
  left: 15px;
  border-top: 150px solid #fbe028;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}

.lightning-border:before {
  top: -140px;
  left: -24px;
  border-bottom: 172px solid #d4c6cb;
  border-left: 38px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
}

.lightning-border:after {
  top: 88px;
  left: 14px;
  border-top: 172px solid #d4c6cb;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 38px solid transparent;
}

.circle {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -90px 0 0 -90px;
}

body {
  background: #e63737;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="z">
    <div class="lg lightning-border"></div>
    <div class="lg lightning"></div>

    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/zZJVyq?editors=1100)

*P.S:* **Ba⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡inga!** ;)

Comment: @Alexandr_T, хром последний, http://prntscr.com/epfbnj , http://prntscr.com/epfbu8 =)

Comment: @Alexandr_T, переделаю без флекс, может быть из-за них рассыпалось все

Answer (score 11):

**Здесь вы найдете информацию по SVG:**

[Circle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle)
[Polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon)

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 150">
  <circle fill="white" stroke="black" cx="50" cy="75" r="50"></circle>
  <polygon stroke="gray" fill="yellow" points="100,0 67,50 90,45 47,100 70,95 0,150 27,110 12,113 50,70 30,73 100,0" />
</svg>
```

### Решение с css

`::before` и `::after`  элементы на молнии. `drop-shadow` в контейнере молнии.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.container {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 0px gray);
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-color: black;
}
.lightning {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: skewX(-30deg) skewY(-30deg) rotate(10deg);
  background-color: yellow;
}
.lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent yellow transparent;
  top: -39px;
  left: -17px;
  content: "";
}
.lightning:after {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
  bottom: -39px;
  right: -17px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lightning"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа:[Create a lightning bolt design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641358/7394871) @Persijn

Answer (score 8):

> Disclaimer:  Я рекомендую SVG для этих целей, но это не означат, что
>   мы не должны получать удовольствие от CSS. Используйте это для
>   обучения, но не для реализации.

Вот метод для получения формы с помощью всего одного элемента, плюс пара псевдоэлементов, и некоторых `background linear-gradients`. Форма может адаптироваться без каких-либо искажений.

**Пояснение того, как была получена форма:**

- Белый круг с черной рамкой является обычным кругом CSS, созданным с
  использованием `border-radius` для псевдоэлемента `:after`.
- Добавлен еще один псевдоэлемент - `:before`, который искажается вдоль
  обеих осей `X` и `Y`, чтобы придать частям молнии нужный вид.
- Молния фактически создается путем укладки нескольких линейных
  градиентов друг на друга. Она включает в себя 6 градиентных
  изображений, где 3 для внутренней желтой части молнии, а другие 3 для
  серых границ.
- Размер фоновых изображений (градиентов)    определяется размером
  молнии, и каждый из них позиционируется таким    образом, чтобы они
  рисовали молнию подобно её внешнему виду.
- Центральная часть молнии фактически имеет только один сплошной цвет, 
  но все еще производится с использованием градиента, потому что мы не 
  можем контролировать размер сплошного цвета фона.

```css
   .lightning {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.lightning:after,
.lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.lightning:after {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.lightning:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, yellow 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, yellow 43%, gray 43%, gray 44%, transparent 44%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 56%, gray 56%, gray 57%, yellow 57%), linear-gradient(transparent 0%, gray 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, gray 51%, transparent 51%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49%, gray 49%);
  background-size: 20% 40%, 22% 42%, 22% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%;
  background-position: 50% 50%, 32% 5%, 70% 100%, 50% 50%, 33% 7%, 69% 98%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
.lightning {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.lightning:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script used only for avoidance of prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="lightning"></div>
```

**Пример с анимацией молнии:**

```css
.lightning {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.lightning:after, .lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.lightning:after {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.lightning:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, yellow 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, yellow 43%, gray 43%, gray 44%, transparent 44%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 56%, gray 56%, gray 57%, yellow 57%), linear-gradient(transparent 0%, gray 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, gray 51%, transparent 51%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49%, gray 49%);
  background-size: 20% 40%, 22% 42%, 22% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%;
  background-position: 50% 50%, 32% 5%, 70% 100%, 50% 50%, 33% 7%, 69% 98%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
.lightning {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.lightning:hover:before {
  animation: boltstrike 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes boltstrike {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(7.5%) translateY(-7.5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
}
@keyframes boltstrike {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5%) translateY(-5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="lightning"></div>
```

[Ссылка](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/LVWXoM/) на `демо` в полный экран  с анимацией и изменением цвета.

Перевод ответа: [Create a lightning bolt design (like The Flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643451/7394871) @Harry